# Alternative Methods of Calculating Center of Mass

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

(This is my first question here.)

[image]

I understand that the center of mass of the disk-with-hole above is $(\frac{1}{3} R, 0)$ using the definition of CM. I've thought of an alternative method of calculating the CM, but it does not work and I have no idea why.

The basic concept is thinking the disk as a sum of a full $2R$ radius disk and a $R$ radius full negative-mass disk. We have to sum up (or integrate) each $m_{i} \overrightarrow{r_{i}}$, and since $m_{i}$ is negative we can 'give' the minus sign to the corresponding $\overrightarrow{r_{i}}$ vector.

By doing that for all $i$, we can make the negative mass disk to a positive mass disk but at a different position - with all of its position vectors multiplied by $-1$. (There cannot be a problem here since both sums and integrals have linear properties.)

Then, the small disk gets 'reflected' by the $y$ axis, and we can calculate the CM considering it as a CM of two objects.

However there is a problem here - it only works when we still consider it as a negative mass, since $\frac{0 + MR}{4M - M} = \frac{1}{3} R$. This is nonsense since we already considered the negative mass, and made it positive by reversing every single position vector.

Also, if we change the axis and let the new $y$ axis be $x = -2R$ (from the original axis), then the CM is not only different from $\frac{1}{3} R$ but also different from the 'probably wrong answer' that we derived from the original axis, considering the disk as a positive mass. This clearly shows that we should still consider the $R$ radius disk as a negative mass.

Can anyone explain why we should still consider it as a negative mass after reflecting all of its position vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think where you are tripping yourself up is when you say

> There cannot be a problem here since both sums and integrals have linear properties.

The problem is that the center of mass position is not given directly by a sum or an integral;  it is given by the *ratio* of two sums/integrals.  Your method leaves one of them the same but actually changes the other one.

Specifically, we have
$$
\mathbf{r}_{CM} = \frac{\sum_i m_i \mathbf{r}_i}{\sum_i m_i}
$$
We can imagine formally writing out both the numerator and the denominator as a sum over "positive" masses and "negative" masses:
$$
\mathbf{r}_{CM} = \frac{\sum_i m_i \mathbf{r}_i + \sum_j m_j \mathbf{r}_j}{\sum_i m_i + \sum_j m_j}
$$
where all the $m_i$ in the first sums (in the numerator and denominator) are positive and all the $m_j$ in the second sums are negative.

Your proposal is to replace $m_j \to m_j' = - m_j > 0$ and simultaneously switch $\mathbf{r}_j \to \mathbf{r}'_j = - \mathbf{r}_j$.  If we do this, we obtain
$$
\mathbf{r}_{CM} = \frac{\sum_i m_i \mathbf{r}_i + \sum_j m'_j \mathbf{r}'_j}{\sum_i m_i - \sum_j m'_j}
$$
All of the $m'_j$ masses entering into the sums are positive now, but the contribution from the "negative masses" must still be negative in the denominator.  We can't actually change it to the form you seem to think it should be because in general
$$
\frac{\sum_i m_i \mathbf{r}_i + \sum_j m'_j \mathbf{r}'_j}{\sum_i m_i + \sum_j m'_j} \neq \frac{\sum_i m_i \mathbf{r}_i + \sum_j m'_j \mathbf{r}'_j}{\sum_i m_i - \sum_j m'_j}
$$

Comment: Thanks. Now I got it